# Is there a simple way to use Oange3 with an Nvidia GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, orange

I need to compute a high dimension dataset, with clustering on Orange3 app. So, there's too many time spent to calculate the Distance Matrix between the objects. If I could use a graphic card for this tasks it will take much less time to complete the task. Anyone know, let's say, a workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Orange uses numpy arrays and computes distances on CPU. Short of reimplementing the routine for calculation of distances (which in itself is rather short and simple), there's nothing you can do about it.

Orange will start using Dask in some not too distant future, but until then try reducing your data set. You may not need all dimensions and/or objects for your clustering.

Comment: So, I will try to use PCA to reduce dimensionality and try do compute the distance matrix from there on. Thanks